# Finding the angle of inclination given the work done by friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

My question pertains to part (ii) of the following question:
[image]
In part i, I found that the speed at point B is $ 7 m/s$.

Now, in part ii, there are two ways to approach the question. The first uses the work done formula to find the **force of friction**, and then proceeds to use the $Fnet = ma$ formula to figure out $\theta$. I successfully found the correct answer for $\theta$.

The second uses kinetic energy gain. This concept is a particular weak point of mine, and I have not been able to use to get the correct answer.
Here is what I did:

$$TME_i + W_{ext} = TME_f$$
$$KE_i + PE_i + W_{ext} = KE_f + PE_f$$
$$(\frac{1}{2}*(0.8)*3^2) + (0.8*10*8sin\theta) + 7 = (\frac{1}{2}*(0.8)*7^2) + 0$$
$$3.6 + 64sin\theta + 7 = 19.6$$
$$64 sin\theta = 9$$
$$\theta = 8.08 (degrees)$$

The answer ought to be $\theta = 21.1$.

My answer key did the following, and I'm not sure what formula they are using or why it works. This is not a conservative system, because there is friction, so how is kinetic energy gain equal to potential energy loss?

[image]

So, in short, two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in my working?
2. What did the answer key do and why?

Note: g is assumed to be 10.

Comment: Please don't post images, use block quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Okay for your **first part** :

I think you made the mistake with the sign of the $W_{ext}$ . Since friction is acting opposite to the direction of its displacement , the work done by friction force should be $F_r s \;cos( 180°)$  i.e. negative work done. So , try it with this change.

For your **second question** :

The answer key used the fact that the change in kinetic energy is equal to the change in its potential energy if no external work is done and it is equal to $mg∆h$.

When it was at its highest position , it had some kinetic energy as well as potential energy . If there were no friction i.e. smooth inclined plane, the change in kinetic energy would have been greater and equal to the change in its potential energy but since friction does a negative work, it takes away some energy from that body and since we know the change in the kinetic energy for the total motion , we can evaluate the change in its potential energy but this time we must add the energy the body lost due to friction since it was the energy of the body itself and finally ithe answer key equalised this change with $mg∆h$.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: @A Level Student was that helpful ?

Comment: I got the first question correct, thank you. For the second question: let me rephrase what I think I understand. If this were a conservative system with no external forces (which it is not due to fric), the increase in kinetic energy as it goes down the inclined slope would be equal to the loss in potential energy. This, however, is a non-conservative system. So some of original energy is used up in working against friction. What the answer key did was, it took the change in KE and subtracted from it the work done by friction (7 J)? And that was the change in PE?

Comment: @A Level Student friction took away some energy . So it did -7J work , negative shows that force was opposing the motion. Now if we would like to know about the total potential energy change from A to B then we will have to  add its change in  kinetic energy and the energy it lost due to friction because it was the body's energy and so in the whole path it transformed some of it 's potential into kinetic and some lost to friction. So total change in the gravitational potential energy is the sum of the change in kinetic energy and the energy lost.

Comment: @A Level Student **If this were a conservative system with no external forces (which it is not due to fric), the increase in kinetic energy as it goes down the inclined slope would be equal to the loss in potential energy. This, however, is a non-conservative system.** Yes , you are right. Because of friction , it had lost some more energy in the form of heat . So total change in potential energy must include that heat energy also.

Comment: @A Level Student was it clear ?

Answer (score 0):

You have given the $7$ Joules lost due to friction the wrong sign - it should be $-7$ not $+7$.

You should have

$3.6 + 64\sin\theta - 7 = 19.6 \\ \Rightarrow 64 \sin\theta = 23 \\ 
\Rightarrow \sin \theta = \frac {23}{64} \approx 0.36 \\ \Rightarrow \theta \approx 21.1^o$

The answer key has the same four terms in its energy equation as you have, just arranged slightly differently. You have

Initial KE + PE lost - energy lost due to friction = final KE

and the answer key has

Final KE - initial KE + energy lost due to friction = PE lost